# Optimizing replace() of Pandas to replace values other than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace values other than 0 in an column named "holiday" of a panda dataframe. The current code is:

```
df['holiday'].replace(to_replace = not '0' , value = '1', inplace = True)
```

But this code is not working and either not generating any error. I can iterate the whole column and then can change the values but it will be too time consuming for large datasets. Any fast alternatives would be appreciable.

This one is working:

```
 df.loc[df['holiday'] != '0', 'holiday'] = 1
```

But still if replace can be optimized to do that.

Sample Dataset:

[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample data please

Comment: @cs95 Done please review.

Comment: loc is faster than replace, so use the working code you have. Besides, replace can't do a "replace everything BUT this" kind of operation that you're looking for.

Comment: ok But can you please tell me what this is actually doing "to_replace = not '0'" as this seems to be a valid syntax because it is not generating any error but its not functional so whether not is getting ignored here or what?

Comment: type `not '0'` into an interpreter and see what is returned. You are telling `replace` to replace the result of that expression with whatever (that result just so doesn't happen to exist in your column, so nothing happens).